# catch exit code in bash script output to screen and log

Tags: bash, logging, output, exit, return-code

I'm trying to combine 2 lines that work separately, but I can't get them to work together. To capture and exit code of 1:

```
Python script.py > /logfile.log 2>&1
ret=$?
if [ $ret -ne 0 ]; then
     exit $ret
fi
```

To output the result of the script to the screen and a log file:

```
Python script.py 2>&1 | tee /logfile.log
```

I want to combine these 2 commands so that the script will output to the screen and log file, and will also catch the exit code of 1 to abort the script when it fails. I tried combining them in different ways, but the script either continues running, or nothing is output to the screen. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: As an aside, your original code is just a pretzel way of writing `Python script.py > /logfile.log 2>&1 || exit`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern - and probably you can easily get rid of the `Python` before the script name by putting a correct shebang.

Comment: @tripleee I tried the command, and it exited with code 1, and logged to file, but didn't output to the screen.

Comment: Indeed, I am pointing out an error in your original command, not trying to answer your question about how to make it do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array PIPESTATUS:

```
Python script.py 2>&1 | tee /logfile.log
ret="${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
if [[ "$ret" -ne "0" ]]; then
  exit "$ret"
fi
```

From `man bash`:

> `PIPESTATUS`: An array variable (see Arrays below) containing a list of exit status values from the processes in the most-
>                 recently-executed foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).

Comment: Thanks the answer helped me aswell. I wanted to ask if I run a script similar to the one above in background is there any way to track its PIPESTATUS(like it mentions to track only recently executed foreground or maybe I misunderstood)?

Comment: I suggest to start a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57345485/is-pipestatus-of-processes-running-in-background-trackable