# Is PIPESTATUS of processes running in background trackable?

Tags: bash, pipestatus

Extending the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57345268/catch-exit-code-in-bash-script-output-to-screen-and-log/57345338?noredirect=1#comment101178704_57345338) as suggested by Cyrus, I wanted to know if I could track the same script with `PIPESTATUS` or something similar if I sent it to run in background?

bash script is as follows:

```
#! /bin/bash

{ python script.py 2>&1  | tee logfile.log; } &
ret="${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
if [[ "$ret" -ne "0" ]]; then
  echo "$ret"
fi
```

and `script.py` is:

```
print("hello")
exit(1);
print("world")
```

When I run the `bash` script without `&` it prints the `PIPESTATUS` correctly but in case when I run it in background, no output is returned.

Comment: It is, but inside subshell, not outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, as Kamil Cuk said, if you want the pipestatus of a background process, you need:

```
{ python script.py 2>&1  | tee logfile.log; exit "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" }
```

But since you're running something in the background, your `if` statement will probably run before it's even completed, so what return value do you expect it to test?

What you typically want is to run something in the background, do a bunch of work, then `wait` for the background task, and only then checking its return value.

`wait` will return the exit status of the background shell, so that's the way to actually get the exit code generated by `exit "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"`